# Recurring crash on SimpleSettableFuture.java in ReactNative

Tags: android, react-native

There is a crash that is showing up repeatedly in Firebase crash reporting for my React Native Android app. However, I am at a loss as to what would be causing it, as the stack trace doesn't cite any of my code. Does anyone know what might be the cause? I am on React Native 0.47.1

The stack trace is as follows:

```
Exception java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.InterruptedException
com.facebook.react.common.futures.SimpleSettableFuture.getOrThrow (SimpleSettableFuture.java:102)
com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl.startNewBackgroundThread (MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:199)
com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl.create (MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:146)
com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.ReactQueueConfigurationImpl.create (ReactQueueConfigurationImpl.java:87)
com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.<init> (CatalystInstanceImpl.java:101)
com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.<init> (CatalystInstanceImpl.java:42)
com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl$Builder.build (CatalystInstanceImpl.java:574)
com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext (ReactInstanceManager.java:999)
com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.access$600 (ReactInstanceManager.java:109)
com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$4.run (ReactInstanceManager.java:802)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:761)

Caused by java.lang.InterruptedException:
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly (AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1301)
java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await (CountDownLatch.java:203)
com.facebook.react.common.futures.SimpleSettableFuture.get (SimpleSettableFuture.java:66)
com.facebook.react.common.futures.SimpleSettableFuture.getOrThrow (SimpleSettableFuture.java:100)
com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl.startNewBackgroundThread (MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:199)
com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl.create (MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:146)
com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.ReactQueueConfigurationImpl.create (ReactQueueConfigurationImpl.java:87)
com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.<init> (CatalystInstanceImpl.java:101)
com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.<init> (CatalystInstanceImpl.java:42)
com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl$Builder.build (CatalystInstanceImpl.java:574)
com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext (ReactInstanceManager.java:999)
com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.access$600 (ReactInstanceManager.java:109)
com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$4.run (ReactInstanceManager.java:802)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:761)
```

Comment: Which android SDK version are you using?

Comment: Also having the same error

Comment: In your manifest file for application what does `android:process` value look like?

Comment: @spooky it is not set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem also occur for many others as well and the cause is various. You can find the discussion about it [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/16959). Since I really don't know what your app does so here is some possible reasons:

1. You're using `react-native-navigation` (you can try change it back to `react-navigation`)
2. You're using `react-native-image-crop-picker` or `react-native-image-picker` (Which produce the same error that make your app crash on some device and it throw `InterruptedException`

If the problem is number 2 you can try to fix it by alter `MainApplication.java`:

```
@Override
public boolean clearHostOnActivityDestroy() {
    return false;
}
```

The fix in number 2 was also reference from [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/16959) under `acintyo` answer.

As for changing the `react-native` version you can try it but I do not recommend it since after reading through the issues mentioned above, I saw that many version also experienced this issues (most of them are 0.49.+ or 0.45.x)

Comment: I am using react-native-navigation as well as react-native-image-picker. With regards to (1) is this just a known bug for that navigator? I searched the github issues.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, regarding (1) - `react-native-navigation` is still a high spectaculation since the bugs for now has only been found in `react-native-navigation`. Also this lib is notorious for not working well with camera :/ You can find issues about it here: https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=camera

Comment: I had same problem, the question(answer) 2 helped me.